# "OPENSSL_1.0.0 not found" on Antergos Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, cmake, openssl, archlinux

I'm developing an App on android studio in an Antergos Linux environment. Everything was going ok with sync, build and debug. A day ago, afer some updates, it does not build anymore. The source code is exactly the same and I already tried to reset my code to older commits that also worked before, so I know that the problem is not from my code. The Gradle Sync Message is:

```
Build command failed.

Error while executing process /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app
-B/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions}

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake:  /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by  /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

Build command failed.

Error while executing process /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake with arguments {-H/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app
-B/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/release/armeabi
-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/home/andre/Development/Edru/edru-android/app/build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/armeabi
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/ninja
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/andre/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-19 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions}

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)

/home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake: /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by /home/andre/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake)
```

I already checked and I have both openssl 1.0 and openssl 1.1. I already reinstaled my OS with a completely fresh android-studio and the problem still exists.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I believe Android now uses BoringSSL, not OpenSSL. Feel free to change the tag back. This path looks wrong: `/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0`. That's usually a `libcrypto` (and `libssl`) for the host machine (your PC); not the target machine (Android device).

Comment: Same issue on Arch, after I updated the system yesterday. I get the error message as soon as I run `$ /opt/android-sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake`.

Comment: I feels like the `cmake` binary I have in `/opt/android-sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake` should be recompiled now that I have a new version of libssl. But it seems to be installed by gradle, so I don't know if I could build it myself...

Comment: `/opt/android-sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake` is installed when I call `gradle clean`, downloaded from `dl.google.com` or something like that. I tried to make a symlink from `/opt/android-sdk/cmake/3.6.3155560/bin/cmake` to my system `cmake` binary, but it did not work. Did you update libssl recently?

Comment: Apparently, the Google version of `cmake` has an "Android Gradle - Ninja" generator that my system `cmake` does not have: `CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja`. So apparently I cannot fix the `cmake` side. Maybe I should downgrade libssl?

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: Both ways worked for me. After I appied them i still had an error, but I just needed to install ncurses back.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is between `cmake 3.6.3155560`, which is coming with Android, and openssl-1.0.2.k-3. If you are up-to-date on Arch Linux, I believe you now have `extra/openssl-1.0 1.0.2.k-3` and `core/openssl 1.1.0.e-1` installed. That was my situation, at least.

In this case, just downgrade `openssl-1.0 1.0.2.k-3` to `openssl-1.0 1.0.2.k-2`, as follows:

**NOTE: it worked for me, but I am not an Arch expert and downgrading a package could have consequences on your system. Do it at your own risk.**

1. Download the package [here](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/o/openssl-1.0/): "openssl-1.0-1.0.2.k-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz"
2. Downgrade to the package you just downloaded with `$ pacman -U openssl-1.0-1.0.2.k-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`
3. As a verification, if you run `pacman -Ss openssl-1.0`, it should tell you:

   > extra/openssl-1.0 1.0.2.k-3 [installed: 1.0.2.k-2]

Of course, `pacman -Syu` will then want to update `openssl-1.0` again.

**UPDATE:** as of today (30-05-2017), it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Stress saver! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having to downgrade you can also download openssl-1.0-1.0.2.k-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz as mentioned above, extract the archive and copy the lib/ files to /usr/local/lib eg
rsync -avz /tmp/openssl-1.0-1.0.2.k-2-x86_64.pkg.tar/usr/lib/ /usr/local/lib

then edit the Android Studio startup script eg /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh and change :
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JAVA_BIN" 
to
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib:$IDE_BIN_HOME:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" "$JAVA_BIN"

Comment: But that means that you will need to actively undo those changes in order to get the new versions of openssl-1.0, right? I think they are fixing the cmake bug (see here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37102629), so in my case I will wait until it is fixed and then update openssl-1.0. But that is a good workaround if one does not want to downgrade the package :-).

Comment: When Android Studio updates it detects the changed startup scripts and asks whether to overwrite it.